# priority_queue Invalid Heap - Debug Assertation Fault

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

I'm experiencing huge problem with priority_queue STL container.

I'm using it to sort objects by parameter x.

Code used to compare by objects parameter.

```
class CompareX {
public:
  bool operator() (MyClass *e1, MyClass *e2) {
      return e1->get_x() > e2->get_x();
  }
};
```

Definition of priority_queue in main:

```
priority_queue<MyClass*, vector<MyClass*>, CompareX > my_queue;
```

Sorting works fine, but here's code where I get Debug Assertation Fault - Invalid Heap:

```
if(condidion == false)
{
  double n = 200;
  my_queue.top()->modifyX(clock, n); //Here I modify parameter X (it becomes bigger)
  my_queue.push(my_queue.top());
  my_queue.pop();
}
```

My goal is to modify parameter X to a bigger one, and re insert object into my_queue to sort it again. What's wrong?

Comment: The moment you modify the top element of the priority queue (in such a way that it compares differently to other members of the pq), you violate an invariant of the `priority_queue` data structure. That's also why `priority_queue` only allows **const** access to the elements. (This doesn't prevent you from breaking it in this case, since you use pointers, hence you'll get access to a const pointer to a mutable element.) A solution: `auto x = my_queue.top(); my_queue.pop(); x->modifyX(clock, n); my_queue.push(x);`

Comment: Off-topic, but I think you probably meant to use `==` in `if(condidion = false)`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just prepared sample code quickly to don't give you full, unnecessary code.